# Msal-angular always opens popup while I prefer redirection

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

In my app.module.ts, I have this configuration for msal-angular:

```
imports: [
 BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
  HttpClientModule,
  FormsModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'ms-profile', component: MsProfileComponent, canActivate: [ MsalGuard ] }
  ]),
  RouterModule,
  MsalModule.forRoot({
    auth: {
      clientId: '7be72f7e-2433-4ef8-b1c7-9b1c91514659',
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com//d566b150-219d-4312-ba59-3dca2f84a2ac',
      validateAuthority: true,
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
    }
  }
)
]
```

Normally (according to documentation) I should get a redirect to login page for aad (Azure Active Directory) but I always get a popup. I want to authenticate via a redirect in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was not a configuration problem but in the way I logged the user in:

```
login() {
    this.authService.loginRedirect();
    // const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;

    // if (isIE) {
    //   this.authService.loginRedirect();
    // } else {
    //   this.authService.loginPopup();
    // }
  }
```

Since `isIE` was false in my case, it did the popup login.

Comment: I have also commented it out but still it opens the popup